# CXF increase connection pool size without changing http.maxConnections

Tags: java, web-services, http, cxf

I have recently been asked to configure CXF to the same parameters as our older XFire service.

One of those parameters was `Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=20`. 
However, I did some research and it appears that CXF uses the JVM `HttpURLConnection` object under the hood. [From what I see](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-291), there has been some attempts to provide configuration for it but nothing has been commited for now.

I would prefer not to change the `http.maxConnections` parameter as it would impact all the server instead of the CXF web services only.

I found this [interresting forum thread](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/HTTP-Connection-Pooling-td561783.html) talking about it where Daniel Kulp says:

> BTW: there is a way to control the connection pooling, but it's a
>   SERVER side  thing.   Basically, if the server sends back a header of:
>
> `Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=5`
>
> then the Java client will respect those values.    Right now in CXF,
>   you would  probably need to write an interceptor to set those values. 
>   I just made a  commit to trunk that expands the http configuration to
>   include a setting to  control this from the config file.

I could write an interceptor that modify the headers to do so. However my question is: How will the server react to this kind of change? Would not that be a problem if the server expects 5 connections max and the client performs more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-keepalive.html), the keep-alive parameters can be controller either by system properties or directly in the HTTP headers:

> The support for HTTP keep-Alive is done transparently. However, it can
>   be **controlled by system properties** http.keepAlive, and
>   http.maxConnections, **as well as** by HTTP/1.1 specified **request and
>   response headers**.