# Java - exact meaning http.maxConnections

Tags: java, oracle, http, concurrency, java-8

Recently I came across 2 slightly different definitions of the java property **http.maxConnections** provided by Oracle.

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) it's defined as

> If HTTP keepalive is enabled this value determines the maximum number of idle connections that will be simultaneously kept alive, per destination.

whereas [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html) it's defined as

> Indicates the maximum number of connections per destination to be kept alive at any given time

What confuses me is the word ***idle*** mentioned in the first definition above. Considering the first definition my understanding is that this property limits **only** the number of connections which are there in the connection pool but that are not used. This means that regardless of this config, I could have un "unlimited" number of active connections towards the same endpoint running at the same time.I don't have the same understanding if I consider the second definition above, where Oracle removed te keyword idle. In this last it seems this property is meant to limit the total number of connections towards an endpoint, so if I configure http.maxConnections=10 I can have at maximum 10 simultaneous calls towards the same endpoint.

Can someone clear my doubts ?

Thanks!

(ps: for the sake of completeness i'm interested in Java8 behavior)

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the second document also talks about (otherwise idle) connections being kept alive by the keep-alive feature.  A new HTTP request will try to re-use one of the existing idle connections if available, but if not, a new connection will be made (there is no limit to that, at least not with this particular configuration option).

Answer (score 2):

Code inspection shows that the property is only used to limit the size of the keep-alive cache - so unless I'm mistaken that's really the maximum number of idle connections.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation libraries use it as ambiguously as the standards language.

for example, apache http components, arguably the most used HTTP client in java, uses it for literal maximum number of concurrent connections to a single host: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#L1005